# Border around text UIButton

Tags: ios, colors, background, uibutton, label

I've a question about UIButton in iOS.
I use Apple UIButton from library and I need that it, when is pressed become "selected" and its background is blue. 
I make anything and it 's working correctly, but around the "label" of title my color is more dark.
I try to set label background to clearColor but it isn't a color of label and I don't know which button subview is.
Any idea? 
I use Objective-C, but if anyone has idea about Swift I understand too.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Did you check whether it's button's background color or not?

Comment: Looks like you set the blue color for Normal state configuration also. Make sure that background color is there for only Selected state configuration

Comment: Are you setting the colors in code? If so, you don't have to. You can configure text and background colors for Normal and Highlighted states from Interface Builder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in

> viewDidLoad()

```
    self.btnDemo.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    self.btnDemo.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    [self.btnDemo setTitle:@"ESTERNO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnDemo setTitle:@"ES" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.btnDemo setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnDemo setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:255 alpha:1.0]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.btnDemo setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnDemo setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Here **btnDemo** is UiButton outlet

- **Below method for convert Color to image**

  ```
  - (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
      CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
      CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

      CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
      CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

      UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

      return image;
  }
  ```

Comment: [button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor: "myColor"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 resolve my problem.